# What is fairness in multi-threading programming?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, multiprocessing

What is thread fairness or fairness in concurrent/multi-threaded programming?

I have googled, there is loads of info on multi-threading but not exactly on fairness.

Can some one explain. An example is most welcome.

Answer (score 9):

Fairness basically resembles to the likelihood that different threads are able to *advance* whatever they are doing. 100% fairness means: all threads should be advancing their work in almost equal portions; 0% fairness means that one single thread might be advancing all the time, and all other threads never (or almost never) make any progress.

It very much depends on your requirements how exactly *fairness* is required or achieved.

Example: the zOS operating system has a component called the *[workload manager](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_61/com.ibm.aix.osdevice/wlm.htm)*. This component works **policy** based. It allows you to say for example: "no matter what, I want that application X always gets 80% of CPU power; Y is important too, Z I dont care". That could mean: when the system gets under intensive load (so 100% of the CPUs consumed all the time) - X gets 80%, Y gets 20%, and Z gets nothing.

Taking this "process" view down to threads: in an *unfair* setup, threads might be *starving*. Meaning: some threads are able to advance, but other threads never get CPU cycles, therefore they can *never* do what they are supposed to do. And please note: thread fairness is not (necessarily) connected to system load.

See [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/starvation-and-fairness.html) for further reading.

Comment: P.S., if you are worried about "fairness," that _may_ be a sign that your threads are not cooperating with one another.  Threads belonging to the same process should always cooperate to solve whatever problem.

Comment: @jameslarge I don't fully agree here. You see, if you are running an application server like Tomcat, Websphere - then there will be hundreds of threads for that one JVM process. Do they *all* need to cooperate? Sure not. Of course: when you have multiple threads within one application, then they *might* depend on each other. But I would actually tend to an opposite view: your threads should not be related. Because: when they are - then you got worried about fairness!

Comment: OK, you're talking about a single-process that serves _competing users_,... where each thread acts as a user's agent.  I'm an old embedded systems guy. Sounds like it's time for me to meditate on how data center guys could have different ideas from mine about how and why we use threads.

Comment: @jameslarge Could very well be the same user. Like one application that does a lot of different things for one user. And I think there are many many reasons to use threads. Thus it isn't possible to put up simple rules that work for all situations.

Comment: This answer and the linked source are misleading. What is described here is called *liveness*. The fairness property, however, does not require the threads to make any progress at all. You get weak fairness if every thread that is almost always enabled, also executes infinitely often. And you get strong fairness if every thread that is infinitely often enabled, also executes infinitely often in its enabled states. **BUT**: if these preconditions are not satisfied, fairness does require the threads to do anything at all. In particular "starvation" does not mean "not fair", it means "not live".

Answer (score 0):

A measure, probably, of how equally every thread gets a chance at execution.

A round-robin approach would be the most *fair* multi-threading approach. This is because here every thread is **guaranteed** to get a chance at execution.

A priority-based one, would be less fair, but preferred in some scenarios. Lower priority threads may get pushed to the bottom of the pile.